# How to resume to the launcher app from the deep link app on Android?

Tags: android, deep-linking

So I have two apps as described below:

**Merchant App**

1. User choose their desired items.
2. User clicks on the checkout button. This will open the Payment App via deep link

**Payment App**

1. Payment App picks up the information passed by Merchant App and display it.
2. User clicks confirm and user will be asked to swipe their credit card to complete payment.
3. Once payment is completed, the Payment App shall send the payment status back to the Merchant App thus close itself.

**Issue**

How do I resume back to the Merchant App from the Payment App after it is being deep inside (few activities in) in Payment App? Because at the moment, every time I try to finish the activity, it will go to the Main Activity of the Payment App.

**Illustration of the issue**

> Merchant App (Checkout Activity) -> Payment App (Confirm Activity) ->
>   Payment App (Payment Activity) -> Payment App (Main Activity)

**Illustration of what I'm trying to achieve**

> Merchant App (Checkout Activity) -> Payment App (Confirm Activity) ->
>   Payment App (Payment Activity) -> Merchant App (Checkout Activity) ->
>   Merchant App (Status Activity)

**Code**

*Merchant App - Checkout Activity*

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

//Verify if receiver app XXX this screen path
PackageManager packageManager = this.context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
if (isIntentSafe) {
     ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 2) {
        String message = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

*Payment App - Payment Activity*

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "test");
setResult(2, intent);
finish();
```

Please advice on where am i making mistake here? Or it is not a good practice to do such thing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is:

- Use a temporary activity call `Payment Confirm Activity` in Payment App to clear all previous activities of Payment App and start a deep link to Merchant App
- You should use another `Checkout Activity` for handling the result from `Payment App`, let's say it's `Checkout Confirm Activity`

So the flow will be:

> Merchant App (Checkout Activity) -> Payment App (Confirm Activity) ->
>   Payment App (Payment Activity) -> **Payment App (Payment Confirm Activity)** -> **Merchant App (Checkout Confirm Activity)** ->
>   Merchant App (Status Activity)

Steps:

1/ `PaymentActivity` will start `PaymentConfirmActivity` to clear all the previous activities using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PaymentConfirmActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

2/ `PaymentConfirmActivity` is generally blank, it starts a deep link to Merchant App to notify the result, including all input data

3/ This `CheckoutConfirmActivity` will handle the result from the `Payment App` by the deep link above (configured format in `AndroidManifest`). Get the input, get the result and show a confirmation page

Edited: You can reuse Merchant App **CheckoutActivity** (no need for `CheckoutConfirmActivity`) by applying `singleTop` launch mode. Found a blog post [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-launch-mode-787d28952959). `CheckoutActivity` can receive the result in `onNewIntent` if it's still the topmost activity in MerchantApp

4/ Move to `StatusActivity` like normal

Comment: Implemented your solution. Works fine however, there are now two apps running on the background. Merchant App with Payment App instance and Payment App with Merchant App instance. How do i close each app after each deep link call?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can use `singleTop` launch mode to reuse CheckoutActivity from MerchantApp. An app cannot be closed programmatically, but it can be empty with no activity left. When PaymentApp start MerchantApp, there is only 1 `ConfirmPaymentActivity` activity left, you can finish it and PaymentApp will be empty, no worried